# Collect Input from a Java JTextarea

Tags: java, swing, text, input, jtextarea

I'm working on one of my first java applets and I want to start of fairly simple (though I have a good understanding of how code works I dont know much in terms of what methods I all have at my disposal when using java)

I have created a Jframe window that has a JTextarea in it. I would like to execute certain lines of code when certain things are typed into this box. In essence, its a simple text input system. How would I go about doing this or is there a better component to use for this?

Comment: improve your question by adding some code you have tried so far

Comment: It might be simpler to use a `JTextField` and a `ActionListener` and/or some buttons which allow to get the text from the field when it's activated

Comment: Chaitanya, Thanks for the recommendation but the problem is that I haven't tried much because I don't know where to begin. I'm rather new to java and I don't even know how to reference what text is currently in the field (i'm going to change it to a field, the only reason i didnt before hand was because I didnt know that such a thing existed.) I suppose that, if i did know how to get what text is currently in the field, i could just trigger the getting of the text when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: Wait, is getting the text from the field really as simple as _textfield_.getText(); ? wow. My problem is that i don't know that alot of useful things exist already within java and whenever i read the documentation, I seem to get lost in a sea of text and end up not getting anything out of it. Sorry for wasting everyone's time and thanks for your help.

Comment: *"..applets and I want to start of fairly simple.."*  Applets are harder to get working and deployed than desktop applications (i.e. based around `JFrame`).  Start with applications first.

Comment: thats what I meant. sorry, i get the two terms confused sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to `getText()`, for `JTextField` some prefer the `getDocument()` method. In Java, `Listener`s are used to capture events, such as "what was typed to the text area". This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) will get you started, if you have trouble implementing you can come back with a more specfic question and some code :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that this question was sloppy and rushed but, at the time of asking it, I dont have a whole lot of time today to play with my code and I needed a quick answer and I felt there was a simple answer to it. for some reason I couldnt think of how to phrase my question in a search engine in a way that would return useful results so I asked here. Thanks again and I'll definitely check out that tutorial!